# force !important class with js-jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, maps

i have a page with google custom search , i have a div class  and i want change the width to 100%, no i tried to set

```
.gs-webResult {width:100%!important;}
```

i tried also :

```
<script>$('.gs-webResult').width('100%');</script>
```

but not change , when reload the page remain with previus setting how can I force the class so that it becomes width: 100%, with css or js or other methods?

note: if use "stylebot" tool for chrome work

but when insert `.gs-webResult {width:100%!important;}` in css and reload the page not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.gs-webResult').css('width', '100% !important');
```

Edit:
It sound a bit like you want it to stay even if the page is reloaded, if so, then you have to make this change every time the page loads, in a:

```
$(function() { });
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar 42k points, still haven't found the "1 new answer" button/link :D

Comment: not work , i tested this 
<script>

$(function() { $('.gs-webResult').css('width', '100% !important');
});
</script>

Comment: Are you sure the class is "gs-webResult" ?

Comment: yes, i test with stylebot tool of google chrome and work(css), but if insert in a php page  and reload not change anithing, the script in the source code compare

Comment: Okay, can you see in your browsers inspecter it's being set on the div/object ?  
If not, do you get any error in the inspecter ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82197/discussion-between-themich-and-djip).